# Passing a session variable through paypal button

Tags: paypal, session-variables

I have setup a simple PayPal BuyNow button.

1. User clicks the button
2. User goes to paypal to purchase
3. User is redirected to a Secure Download Page

The problem I'm having is accessing the Download Page. It should be accessed through a session variable passed into it.

How do I pass a session variable through a PayPal BuyNow button?

Should it be passed from the button code? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

A session variable does not get passed like a form variable does.  So Paypal wouldn't have anything to do with this unless you are getting their response information to create the session variable.

Session variables are created and stored on the web server for the duration of the browsing session (until the user closes their browser) or for the length of time that you specify in your code (1 day, 10 days, 30 days, etc...).  They are not dependent on the page being viewed. If you create this variable before submitting the paypal button, when the user accesses the download page, your code should read the variable and allow the user to do whatever you have programmed for them to do.

One note, however, is that a user has to have cookies enabled for session variables to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: upon further thought of this topic,  there are a couple of ways you could accomplish this task.  You could have paypal redirect to a page that creates the session variable before then redirecting to your download page.  You could also use one of the other numerous form variables when submitting your paypal button, so when Paypal redirects to your download page, the session variable is contained within one of the other form variables returned from Paypal.

If you need additional guidance, post some code and I can see if I can help further.